# StoredProcedureQuery with Multiple out parameter not working after hibernate(6) and java (17) upgrade

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-criteria

Earlier StoredProcedureQuery with two out parameter is working. I successfully called a stored procedure with two out and multiple IN parameters. But after java and hibernate upgrade it is not working as expected. (in stored procedure char, String, Integer IN and OUT parameter)

I want to called stored procedure with two OUT and multiple IN parameters in hibernate 6 and java 17.

Comment: "Not working" is not an error message. If does not work it produced an error. Please add it to the question.

Comment: No Error message Gimby. But not getting expected output.If you know any changes need to do in storeProcedueQuery after Hibernate 6. Is that supported by Hibernate proprly.Any changes we need to in hibernate 6 to work.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to Java 17 and hibernate 6, the sequence of `IN` parameter was changed. I was able to fix this by changing the sequence while sending the `IN` parameter to the procedure.